# jQuery qTip is not working after calling it using .html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing problem for jQuery qTip while data is coming dynamically through JS.

**jQuery qTip plugin doesn't work for below code**

```
var data = '';
data = '<div class="cont">';
data =+ '<a href="#" class="qTip"></a>';
data =+ '</div>';

$('#container').html(data);
```

**but it works when I place the anchor tag directly to html markup.**

```
<a href="#" class="qTip"></a>
```

Comment: you have to reinitialize qTip plugin on new added element. Some plugin support kind of delegation, i don't think it is the case for qTip plugin

Comment: #Wolf.. yeah.. it's not problem of qTip plugin.. it's event re-bind problem. once data is coming dynamically it's getting registered with DOM and forgets. I want to re-bind the same event.. if you can show me some syntax for that?

Comment: How do you initialize qTip? I need to see it before providing any code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I assume, possibly you could attach an event again after document finish load..

```
$('.qTip').on('click', function(){
  $(this).qTip();
});
```